# Loop within loop when comparing csv files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two csv files. I am trying to look up a value the first column in one file (file 1) in the first column in the other file (file 2). If they match then print the row from file 2.

Pseudo code:

```
read file1.csv
read file2.csv
loop through file1
compare each row with each row of file 2 in turn
    if file1[0] == file2[0]:
        print row of file 2
```

file1:

```
45,John
46,Fred
47,Bill
```

File2:

```
46,Roger
48,Pete
49,Bob
```

I want it to print :
`46 Roger`

EDIT - these are examples, the actual file is much bigger (5,000 rows, 7 columns) 
I have the following:

```
import csv
with open('csvfile1.csv', 'rt') as csvfile1, open('csvfile2.csv', 'rt') as     csvfile2:
    csv1reader = csv.reader(csvfile1)
    csv2reader = csv.reader(csvfile2)
    for rowcsv1 in csv1reader:
        for rowcsv2 in csv2reader:
            if rowcsv1[0] == rowcsv2[0]:
                print(rowcsv1)
```

However I am getting no output.

I am aware there are other ways of doing it (with dict, pandas) but I cam keen to know why *my* approach is not working.

EDIT: I now see that it is only iterating through the first row of file 1 and then closing, but I am unclear how to stop it closing (I also understand that this is not the best way to do do it).

Comment: Have you tried printing out what rowcsv1[0] & rowcsv2[0] are at each iteration? It's likely that there's some mismatching going on with the indexing causing the error.

Comment: You need to store all of file2 but you can do a one-shot iteration of file1. Probbably no need for csv at all in this particular case since you can just compare the lines as strings.

Comment: These are examples, the actual file is much bigger (5,000 rows, 7 columns)

Comment: ... 5000 rows is nothing; you can do tens of millions of rows if you have enough memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You open `csv2reader = csv.reader(csvfile2)` then iterate through it vs the first row of `csv1reader` - it has now reached end of file and will not produce any more data.

So for the second through last rows of `csv1reader` you are comparing against the items of an empty list, ie no comparison takes place.

In any case, this is a very inefficient method; unless you are working on very large files, it would be much better to do

```
import csv

# load second file as lookup table
data = {}
with open("csv2file.csv") as inf2:
    for row in csv.reader(inf2):
        data[row[0]] = row

# now process first file against it
with open("csv1file.csv") as inf1:
    for row in csv.reader(inf1):
        if row[0] in data:
            print(data[row[0]])
```

Comment: So how do I get it to iterate through rows 2 and 3? Am I misunderstanding with/as?

Comment: I'm so backward in python :-(  Doesn't data[row[0]] just take the data at index [0]? Or is that notation for the whole row?

Comment: `row[0]` gets your key value (ie 46); then `data[46]` gets the corresponding row, ie `[46, "Roger"]`.

Comment: If my csv files had three columns could I still use this dictionary-style approach?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Actually the code above should work as-is for that (assuming you key on a single column).

Comment: Sorry, badly worded. I mean could I output 46, Roger, Blue from csvfile2 if it had three columns for age, name, color (and assuming I still matched on first column)?

Answer (score 1):

See Hugh Bothwell's answer for why your code isn't working. For a fast way of doing what you stated you want to do in your question, try this:

```
import csv
with open('csvfile1.csv', 'rt') as csvfile1, open('csvfile2.csv', 'rt') as csvfile2:
    csv1 = list(csv.reader(csvfile1))
    csv2 = list(csv.reader(csvfile2))
    duplicates = {a[0] for a in csv1} & {a[0] for a in csv2}
    for row in csv2:
        if row[0] in duplicates:
            print(row)
```

It gets the duplicate numbers from the two csv files, then loops through the second cvs file, printing the row if the number at index 0 is in the first cvs file. This is a much faster algorithm than what you were attempting to do.

Comment: This is an interesting alternate solution; just keep in mind that the order of output will be different (it will be in row-order by file2 instead of by file1). This may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters, as @hugh-bothwell's mentioned in @will-da-silva's answer, you could do:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('csvfile1.csv', 'rt') as csvfile1, open('csvfile2.csv', 'rt') as csvfile2:
    csv1 = list(csv.reader(csvfile1))
    csv2 = list(csv.reader(csvfile2))

d = {row[0]: row for row in csv2}
k = OrderedDict.fromkeys([a[0] for a in csv1]).keys()
duplicate_keys = [k for k in k if k in d]
for k in duplicate_keys:
    print(d[k])
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this, but try out this solution, it should work.

```
counter = 0
import csv
with open('csvfile1.csv', 'rt') as csvfile1, open('csvfile2.csv', 'rt') as     
csvfile2:
    csv1reader = csv.reader(csvfile1)
    csv2reader = csv.reader(csvfile2)
    for rowcsv1 in csv1reader:
       for rowcsv2 in csv2reader:
           if rowcsv1[counter] == rowcsv2[counter]:
               print(rowcsv1)
           counter += 1   #increment it out of the IF statement.
```

Comment: The structure looks similar to mine (for, for, if, action) - what is it which is stopping the iteration closing after row 1 of file1 as is happening with mine?

Comment: This is a non-solution. The problem is that you can only iterate over the contents of csv2reader once; introducing a counter variable does nothing to change that.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell In that case, populate a dictionary with the contents from csv and then iterate through it?

Comment: That is my preferred solution - use your one pass over the file to store it to memory for later reference. You could store it as a list, but then looking up values in it is O(n) instead of O(1); a dict is much faster for this particular usage.