# Compare few entries based on column in one CSV file against another large CSV - Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to compare 2 CSV files, where first one only has couple of entries and the other one has 300 lines. The output I am trying to achive is to print the output of the line from the large file if column email from file1.csv matches the column email from file2.csv matches but the date doesn't. I would like to do this using the "CSV" module. Here is an example:

file1.csv (few entries):

```
Tom,Johns,tom.johns@email.com,14 May 2017
Imaginary,User,imaginary@email.com,23 May 2018
```

file2.csv (large file):

```
First,User,first.user@email.com,10 Jan 2018
Second,User,second.user@email.com,13 Feb 2018
Tom,Johns,tom.johns@email.com,16 Jun 2017
Imaginary,User,imaginary@email.com,23 May 2018
```

result.csv (Desired result)

```
Tom,Johns,tom.johns@email.com,16 Jun 2017
```

I tried achieving this using the function "next" but due to only 2 entries in file1.csv the script stops. I have rewritten the code but now I am getting I/O operation on closed file.

```
import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as first_csv:
    dialect = csv.excel()
    file1 = csv.reader(first_csv, dialect)

with open('file2.csv', 'r') as second_csv:
        dialect = csv.excel()
        file2 = csv.reader(second_csv, dialect)

writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'w'))

output = set()

for row1 in file1:
        for row2 in file2:
                if (row1[2] == row2[2]) and (row1[3] != row1[3]):
                        writer.writerow(row2)
                        output.append(row2)
```

Comment: It may be a lot easier(and faster) to input each of the csv files into separate SQLite  tables and then join the tables. More reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html, https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html. @StefanosGkouts

Comment: @Mr.Zeus I'm pretty new in Python, so still getting my head around the basics. I would prefer to do it using "import csv", apologies for not mentioning this. I have updated the initial post.

Comment: In that case @Python_Rookie, I will get back to you with the pure Python & `csv` code, I am just a in the middle of something.

Comment: I just realized it is because when you use the `with`statement, thus closing the I/O stream when you reach the end of it. I fixed that but there is still an issue with your logic.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2WW97TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by converting the CSV to list. Here is the final code:

```
import csv

first_csv = open('file1.csv', 'r')
second_csv = open('file2.csv', 'r')
output_csv = open('result.csv', 'w')

file1 = csv.reader(first_csv, csv.excel())
file2 = csv.reader(second_csv, csv.excel())
writer = csv.writer(output_csv)

output = []
list1 = list(file1)
list2 = list(file2)

for row1 in list1:
    for row2 in list2:
        if (row1[2] == row2[2]) and (row1[3] != row2[3]):
            writer.writerow(row2)
            output.append(row2)

first_csv.close()
second_csv.close()
output_csv.close()

print(output)
```

Thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mr.Zeus already said in the comments, the csv files need to stay `open` as long as you're reading or writing on them. Therefore, you can't use the `with` statement here, which closes the files on exit.

Another problem with your code was the `(row1[3] != row1[3])` part, which is ofc always `False` :D

So here's a fixed version. Note the `close` in the `finally` block, which makes sure this will always happen, even if an Exception occurs in the `try` part.

```
import csv

first_csv = open('file1.csv', 'r')
second_csv = open('file2.csv', 'r')
output_csv = open('result.csv', 'w')

try:
    file1 = csv.reader(first_csv, csv.excel())
    file2 = csv.reader(second_csv, csv.excel())
    writer = csv.writer(output_csv)

    output = []
    for row1 in file1:
        for row2 in file2:
            if (row1[2] == row2[2]) and (row1[3] != row2[3]):
                writer.writerow(row2)
                output.append(row2)
finally:    
    first_csv.close()
    second_csv.close()
    output_csv.close()

print(output)
```

Comment: For some reason it only returns `[['Tom', 'Johns', 'tom.johns@email.com', '16 Jun 2017']]` when it should return `[['Tom', 'Johns', 'tom.johns@email.com', '16 Jun 2017'], ["Imaginary", "User", "imaginary@email.com", "23 May 2018"]]` The same thing happened when I adapted my code as well, any thoughts?

Comment: But that's what OP asked for. The `(row1[3] != row2[3])` part is responsible for that - remove it and you get the list with your 2 entries. I just guessed here and left it in.

Comment: @Jeronimo Do you have idea why the code only prints the first match and stops looking further? For example if you make a change in file1 for "Imaginary User"( set the date to "25 Jun 2018") it will still only print "Tom,Johns,tom.johns@email.com,16 Jun 2017" in the result instead of both lines.

Comment: @Python_Rookie Hm yeah you're right. That seems to be because the csv reader only reads through the file once, so you basically cannot loop through it more than one time, which is the case in the inner loop for `row2` here. [That's related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553627/loop-within-loop-when-comparing-csv-files-in-python). I guess then you'll have to read the data into lists and iterate over those.